# Android Share Intent changing PNG to JPG

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to share an image of type PNG using G-mail. But in mail attachment I'm getting JPG.

```
    final Bitmap selectedRowToBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.share_image);       

            if (selectedRowToBmp != null) {

                String pathofBmp = Images.Media.insertImage(hostActivity.getContentResolver(), selectedRowToBmp, null, null);
                Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
                final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);

}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.